# Is this MergeSort implementation stable?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I am studying for my algorithms exam. Someone can explain me why this is not stable and where is the problem that is not becoming stable? And how can I make it stable?

Thanks

```
//The numbers to be sorted are given in array A[1..n]
//We use an additional array B[1..n] as temporary storage space
MergeSort(A, left, right) {
    if (left < right) {
        mid = floor( (left + right)/2 );     // find the middle
        MergeSort(A, left, mid);             // sort the left subarray recursively
        MergeSort(A, mid+1, right);          // sort the right subarray recursively
        Merge(A,left,mid,right);             // merge the two sorted subarrays
    }
}

Merge(A, left, mid, right) {
    // left subarray: A[left..mid], right subarray: A[mid+1 .. right]
    m = left; // index for the temporary array
    i = left;
    j = mid+1;
    while (i <= mid && j <= right) {     // copy the smaller element to the output
        if ( A[i] >= A[j] ) {
            B[m] = A[j];
            j++;
        } else {
            B[m] = A[i];
            i++;
        }
        m++;
    }
    while (i <= mid) {                   // copy the remaining part in the left array
        B[m] = A[i];
        m++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j <= right) {                 // copy the remaining part in the right array
        B[m] = A[j];
        m++;
        j++;
    }
    for (m = left; m <= right; m++)      // copy the merged form back to A
        A[m] = B[m];
}
```

Comment: To best of my knowledge, MergeSort is stable. Quicksort is not.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: @pjs this is the whole code that they gave me to analyse.

Comment: I didn't ask for more code.  I asked that you properly indent what's there.

Comment: @pjs sorry i did not understand that, again one of my friend said that we should change" if (A[i] >=A[j] ) to if (A[i] >A[j] ) "to make it stable but i did not understand why?

Comment: You don't know what indentation is???  Don't align all of your program on the left-most column.  Readability is very important, and indentation is a major element of readability.

Comment: @pjs yes i know what indentation is, but i did not write this code, i just copy paste here from the examples.

Comment: @M.J.Watson You can do as you like, but many people won't even bother looking at your code if you're going to make reading it a challenge.  You'll be doing yourself a huge favor if you learn how to properly format code, regardless of how it was given to you.

Comment: @pjs i will keep it in my mind thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this segment:

```
i = left;
j = mid+1;
while (i <= mid && j <= right) { // copy the smaller element to the output
    if ( A[i] >= A[j] ) {
        B[m] = A[j];
```

That says that if an element from the left part of the array is equal to an element from the right, choose the one from the right.  Doing so will reverse the original ordering of those elements.

Comment: Thank you now i understand it!